# Python: how to cleanup up the messy pop-up list

Tags: python, module, popup, interactive, pyscripter

Quick demonstration of the problem:
Define a module and name it `functions.py` containing: (**this is just an example**)

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy import *

def a():
    return sin(1)
```

Now try to use it in a separate file as follows:

```
import functions as f
```

If you type `f` the pop-up list shows all `scipy` contents while it should be only `a`! See:
[image]

**How to solve this?**

This problem makes difficult to see what in the module `functions` exist.

**Note:**
**1)** Think that the module `function` will have numerous user-defined-functions.
**2)** There is no problem why scipy function are available globally. That's OK. The problem is **why do they appear as member of f**?!
It perhaps is a bug in **Pyscripter**, I am not sure!

Answer (score 2):

Your module `functions` will contain references to everything imported globally and declared inside its scope.

As you're doing `from scipy import *` inside the module it will import everything, as it well should, and you will be able to access all the `scipy` functions from your functions module.

If you only wanted to see  `a()` after importing `functions`, change it to this

```
# functions.py
def a():
    from scipy import sin
    return sin(1)
```

which will ensure that no references to your import will exist for the person importing your module.

Here's some [reading](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) on `imports` you can go through.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid `import *`, thus your code should look like:

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy import sin

def a():
    return sin(1)
```

or

```
from __future__ import division
import scipy

def a():
    return scipy.sin(1)
```

Another alternative is to add this to your module:

```
__all__ = ['a']
```

Comment: I'd say the `__all__` isn't so much an alternative as another part of the solution. @Developer should use one of your two import options *and* set `__all__`.